# "Int object has no attribute" error when calling list object from list obtained by append in custom module

Tags: python

I have to make a counter for the number of times an element occurs in a list using really basic loops with a limited number of operations.
When the I don't use the module and integrate it into the code directly the error disappear.

```
def norepeat(a):
R=[]
i=0
while i<len(a):
    if a[i] in R:
        i=i+1
    else:
        R.append(a[i])
        i=i+1
return R

a=list(input("enter list(elements seperated by commas):"))
L=len(a)
R=norepeat(a)
print R
print R[1]
l=(len(R))
print l
i=0
while i<l:
    j=0
    count=0
    while j<L:
        if R[i]==L[j]:#error:'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
            count+=1
        if j==l-1:
            print R[i],"occurs",count,"times"
    j=j+1
i=i+1

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-73b7f443c37e> in <module>()
 23     count=0
 24     while j<L:
 ---> 25         if R[i]==L[j]:
 26             count+=1
 27         if j==l-1:

 TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Comment: `L=len(a)`. I think you might be mixing up `L` and `l`. Which is why you shouldn't use single char variable names.

Comment: Not just that, but it makes it impossible to read your code and understand what's supposed to happen. Not just for us, but if you came back to this code two weeks later you'd probably realise it's a struggle. Break the habit now. Name your variables properly.

Answer (score 1):

You have `L = len(a)` and then later you have `L[j]`. This results in an error because you are treating L as a list. I believe that you have switched `L` and `l`.

Consider renaming your variables to avoid confusion. Single character variable names are often not best practice.